# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminBookingsController does not exist Laravel-5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to load a calendar on my page using AJAX/Laravel-5.  The URL the AJAX is posting to exists in my `routes.php` file.  However for some reason I keep getting the following error:

`Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminBookingsController does not exist`

**My jQuery call:**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.initCalendar = function(token,month,location) {
        $('#calendar-overlay-wrap').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/reports/bookings/butchers',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 
                _token: token,
                month: month,
                location_id: location
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json['error']) {
                    $('#calendar-overlay-wrap').html(json['msg']);
                }
                $('#calendar').html(json['calendar']);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.initCalendar(
        $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        $('#month').val(),
        $('#location_id').val()
    );
});
```

**My routes.php file:**

```
Route::post('admin/reports/bookings/butchers', 'AdminBookingsController@genButchersReport');
```

**My controller file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Booking;
use App\Location;
use App\ClassType;
use App\Classes;
use App\Http\Requests\BookingSearchRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateBookingRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\BookingReportAccountsRequest;
use Response;
use Excel;
use DB;

class AdminBookingsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Generate booking report for butchers.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function genButchersReport()
    {
        echo "Hi!...";exit;
    }
}
```

I have tried running `composer dump-autoload` but this does not seem to have any effect on the error.

Please help.

Comment: JQuery code doesn't have anything to do with the issue, Could you paste instead your controller class together with namespaces declaration?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I have just added my controller file in my original post

Comment: Are you using route group with some sort of `namespace` set? if yes can you please post your routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this as my controller was inside a sub folder.  I changed my route and now it works.

```
Route::post('admin/reports/bookings/butchers', 'Admin\AdminBookingsController@genButchersReport');
```

Answer (score 1):

This error popped up for me when I accidentally typed `return = $variablename` instead of `return $variablename` in one of my controller files. Maybe it will help somebody.

Comment: I came here because I misspelled Controller (one L). Hope that might help someone in the future.